# JS error on product page Cannot read property '' of undefined _getAttributeCodeById which doesnt allow to load configrable price and image

Tags: magento2

I am getting an error due to which I am not able to get the configurable product price and image being reflected and this error shows when I click on swatch color options.

Below is the image of the error which I am facing.
[image]

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: have you tried cache flush and reindex?

Comment: Yes I had done that..Problem solved.The issue was some other module interfering with this.